# Что происходит в интерактивном режиме (>>>) если ввести строку (или идентификатор проинициализированной переменной) и нажать Enter ?

Tags: python

Просто набираем строку с последующим нажатием Enter:

```
>>> r'hello\"world'
'hello\\"world'
```

Получил не то, что ожидал. Я думал, что должна вызваться функция `print(r'hello\"world')` и распечатать строку *hello\"world*

Теперь так:

```
>>> print(r'hello\"world')
hello\"world
```

Получил то, что ожидал.

Что происходит в интерактивном режиме(>>>) после ввода строки и нажатия на Enter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как при вызове `print`, так и при выводе в интерактивном режиме Python преобразует выражение в строку и выводит её на экран. Различия заключаются в том, что при этом вызываются различные методы преобразования. Если вы имеете понятие об [ООП](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0_Python), то вот Вам небольшой пример:

```
class My:
    def __str__(self):
        return '__str__: Вызывается для print'
    def __repr__(self):
        return '__repr__: Вызывается в интерактивном режиме'

obj = My()
print(obj)
```

После запуска выведет: `__str__: Вызывается для print`
И далее, если в интерактивном режиме ввести сам объект:

```
>>> obj
__repr__: Вызывается в интерактивном режиме
```

И `__repr__`, и `__str__` возвращают строку, которая попадает на экран.
И так происходит со всеми типами данных, в том числе и с Вашей строкой.

Таким образом:

```
>>> a = r'hello\"world'
>>> a #равносильно вызову print(a.__repr__())
'hello\\"world'
>>> print(a) #равносильно вызову print(a.__str__())
hello\"world
```

Comment: Спасибо, все понятно.

Answer (score 3):

В интерактивном режиме используется [`sys.displayhook`, который по умолчанию среди других вещей вызывает `repr(obj)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook):

```
def displayhook(value):
    if value is None:
        return
    # Set '_' to None to avoid recursion
    builtins._ = None
    text = repr(value)
    try:
        sys.stdout.write(text)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        bytes = text.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, 'backslashreplace')
        if hasattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer'):
            sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes)
        else:
            text = bytes.decode(sys.stdout.encoding, 'strict')
            sys.stdout.write(text)
    sys.stdout.write("\n")
    builtins._ = value
```

Назначение [`repr(obj)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) получить *однозначное* текстовое представление объекта (полезно для отладки). Идеально, `eval(repr(obj)) == obj`, например:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 28, 17, 24, 57, 111636)
```

`repr` для `datetime` объекта позволяет воспроизвести его точно.

`print(obj)` может вызывать [`str(obj)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str). Назначение `str(obj)` получить *читаемое* текстовое представление для объекта:

```
>>> print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
2015-07-28 17:24:57.111636
```

`str`, `repr` встроенные функции могут вызывать `__str__`, `__repr__` методы, чтобы реализовать нестандартное поведение. Cтандартное поведение `repr(obj)` не очень полезно:

```
>>> object()
<object object at 0x7fe8a7a560f0>
```

Для Юникодных строк, в Питоне 2 существует `__unicode__` метод:

```
>>> class C:
...   def __str__(self):
...       return "str"
...   def __repr__(self):
...       return "repr"
...   def __unicode__(self):
...       return u"unicode"
... 
>>> C()
repr
>>> print(C())
str
>>> u"%s" % C()
u'unicode'
```

Если `__str__`, `__unicode__` не определены, то используется `repr()` функция:

```
>>> class NoStr:
...    def __repr__(self):
...        return "repr"
... 
>>> NoStr()
repr
>>> print(NoStr())
repr
>>> u"%s" % NoStr()
u'repr'
```

Не следует вызывать `__str__`, `__repr__` напрямую. Эти методы не усиливают возвращаемый тип, в отличии от соответствующих функций.

#### Ссылки

- [Difference between `__str__` and `__repr__` in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703/4279)
- [What is the purpose of `__str__` and `__repr__` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3691101/4279)
- [`__repr__` vs repr](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12877619/4279)

Answer (score 0):

После ввода строки и нажатия на Enter выполняется тот код, который вы ввели.
Почему вы решили, что в первом случае должна вызваться функция `print`?

Comment: Ну вы сами смотрите: мы ввели r'hello\"world', а получили 'hello\\"world'. Не отобразилось же r'hello\"world'. Значит, должно быть, какие-то преобразования все-таки выполнялись

Comment: `'hello\\"world'` - это то, как интерпретатор представляет эту строку. 
А функция `print` обеспечивает дружественный вывод.

Comment: Рекомендую прочитать главу 7 "Строки" из книги Марка Лутца "Изучаем Python". А лучше всего - всю книгу, много полезного оттуда можно почерпнуть.