# Создание специального метода в Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

В PEP8 [сказано](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id36) об именах:

> double leading and trailing underscore: "magic" objects or attributes
>   that live in user-controlled namespaces ... Never invent such names;
>   only use them as documented.

При этом, я могу создать такой класс:

```
class A:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'classA'

    def __str1__(self):
        return 'classA_str1__'

    def __str2(self):
        return 'classA_str2'
```

Причём могу написать так:

```
print(a)
print(a.__str__())
print(a.__str1__())
```

Но не могу так:

```
print(a.__str2())
```

Понятно, что два подчёркивания можно использовать для создания "приватных" методов. Но почему добавление двух подчёркиваний в конце имени метода позволяет вызывать его "снаружи" класса, даже тогда, когда, казалось бы, он должен быть приватным? Почему сказано не изобретать таких имён? Например, я хочу создать свой специальный метод. Получается, это невозможно? А если возможно, то как бы мне это сделать?

Comment: связанный вопрос [Магические методы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/646280/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q**: Но почему добавление двух подчёркиваний в конце имени метода позволяет вызывать его "снаружи" класса, даже тогда, когда, казалось бы, он должен быть приватным?

Потому что механизм сокрытия имён работает только для имён, у которых не больше одного подчёркивания в конце. Из [вводного руководства](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private):

> Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, **at most one trailing underscore**) is textually replaced with _classname__spam<sup>[выделение жирным моё]</sup>

---

> **Q**:  Почему сказано не изобретать таких имён?

Потому что такие `__special__` имена  используются языком. [Их много](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names), могут появляться новые (e.g., [`__set_name__` в 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__set_name__)) — в принципе возможен конфликт. Главное: *люди, читающие ваш код, ожидают, что подобные имена принадлежат языку.* Поведение специальных методов ([как они вызываются](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup)) отличается от обычных методов. Что может вести к тонким отличиям. К примеру, [Python len() и `.__len__()` в чем разница?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/695218/23044)

Что свои протоколы вводить, `__специальные__` имена или методы не нужны. К примеру, [`.quack()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647069/23044). Благодаря duck typing в Питоне, неявные протоколы во многих местах присутствуют, к примеру, `print()` может писать в "file-like" объект вместо `sys.stdout`. Иногда достаточно передать объект с одним `write()` методом. Некоторые устойчивые концепции (типа `Hashable`, `Iterable`) в виде [`ABC` классов формализованы](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html).

Comment: Спасибо, это даже ещё точней! Именно то, что я хотел узнать. Вообще, спасибо за все ответы в разных вопросах, очень подробно и познавательно. И, конечно, восхищает уровень Ваших знаний. Кое-какие из ссылок я и сам видел, но не сообразил даже, что они связаны с моим вопросом.

Comment: А чтоб связывать вопросы, нужен некий определённый рейтинг?

Comment: @Anton: Спасибо, за добрые слова. Любая ссылка на другой Stack Overflow вопрос (в самом вопросе, ответе, комментарии) создаёт связанный вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, нужно разделить несколько частей вопроса:

1. *Почему `.__method__` не ведет себя как `.__method`?*

Просто по определению разработчиков языка. `__method__` - довольно привычная конструкция, используется повсеместно для специальных методов типа **str**(), **repr()** и вообще множества операций, для любопытства можно вывести `dir(1)` или что-то подобное.

`.__method()` - лимитированная конструкция, используется редко и для избежания конфликтов в наследовании, см [тут](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables), фактически это не замена приватным методам в других языках.

2. *Например, я хочу создать свой специальный метод. Получается, это невозможно? А если возможно, то как бы мне это сделать?*

В питоне приватный метод обозначается одним подчеркиванием `_method()`, но это просто синктаксическое соглашение, никаких особых функциональных отличий у него нет (может быть последовательность перечисления в вызове `dir`). Метод виден в `dir`, может вызываться. Прямого способа спрятать метод в питоне, как мне кажется, не предусмотрено.

Comment: Спасибо! Выходит, с осмыслением синтаксиса у меня были проблемы. Тут Вы мне помогли, благодарю! Но конечной целью является создание именно специального метода. То есть, например, хотелось бы именно создать два метода _\_str_\_ и _\_specialStr_\_, которые возвращали бы строки, но разные. И при вызове print(A) вызывалась бы _\_st_\_, а при вызове specialPrint(A) - _\_specialStr_\_

Comment: Не знаю, как вставлять подчёркивания в комментарий( Всё, что у меня выделилось жирным - оно было обрамлено двумя подчёркиваниями.

Comment: @Anton _\_str_\_ это _\\_str_\\_ . `__str__` это `\`__str__\``

Comment: @Anton, можно как код в обратных кавычках: `__str__`

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю вашу логику, вам нужна самостоятельная функция `def specialPrint(x)` - но она может быть связана с вашим классом как угодно, например  `def specialPrint(x):
    print(x._some_attribute)` или то же самое с try-except.

Comment: Большое спасибо, @AndrioSkur!

Comment: Большое спасибо, @MaxU!

Comment: На практике для нового класса я бы советовал просто сделать свои \_\_repr\_\_() (более простой, ориентированный на повтор вызова конструктура) и \_\_str\_\_() (более симпатичный для печати).

Comment: Да, @EvgenyPogrebnyak, Вы правильно поняли, именно так. Просто возник интерес, можно ли сделать, чтоб её вызывать не как print(x._some_attribute), а как, ну например, print2(x)?

Comment: То есть, кажется, я что-то совсем искусственное придумываю, наверное, это и не надо никому, но тут уж любыпотно.

Comment: @Anton, главное, чтобы для вашей задачи это было нужно и укладывалось в конвенции языка. Можно и print2() написать и публичный метод .print2() в классе, но лучше идти от задачи и смотреть как это помогает в работе. Но корежить **\_\_эти_методы\_\_**, имхо, лучше не надо ;)

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak, всё, теперь вопросов не осталось) Большое спасибо Вам за объяснения!

Comment: Чтобы достучаться до `__method`, нужно указывать заместо `__method`, `_ClassName__method`.

Comment: @Anton: `print(x)`  может вызвать специальные методы на типе `x` объекта, которые вы наиболее подходящим способом для вашей задачи можете определить.  [Чем отличается _\_repr_\_ от _\_str_\_?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/534440/23044) А может вам больше подойдет, переопределить `sys.displayhook`. [Что происходит в интерактивном режиме (>>>) если ввести строку (или идентификатор проинициализированной переменной) и нажать Enter ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/438359/23044)